# How do I make a good hash function for large Strings?

Tags: java, hashtable, hashcode

Here's my hash function for Strings

```
public class GoodHashFunctor implements HashFunctor {

    @Override
    public int hash(String item) {

        String binaryRepString = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < item.length(); i++){
            // Add the String version of the binary version of the integer  version of each character in item
            binaryRepString += Integer.toBinaryString((int)(item.charAt(i)));
        }


        long longVersion = Long.parseLong(binaryRepString, 2) % Integer.MAX_VALUE;


        return (int) longVersion;

    }

}
```

However, when I try hashing large Strings (around 10-15 characters), I'm getting errors because when it tries to parseLong, it dies because it's too big a number.

What do you all think I should do? And my professor said we can't use Java's hashCode()

I saw a similar post where the best answer was to hash this way:

```
int hash=7;

for (int i=0; i < strlen; i++) {
    hash = hash*31+charAt(i);
}
```

But wouldn't I run into the same problem? I guess it'd probably take a lot longer Strings to break it this new way. I dunno I'm fairly confused...

Comment: Why don't you look at String's default hash algo?

Comment: @Silver: there is HashBuilder from apache commons. Isn't it sufficient for you?

Comment: Ah, thanks, I thought that String's default hash algo was hidden (noob mistake)

So it's s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]

Also, Kowser, I'm looking into the HashBuilder thing, but not exactly understanding it. But I think I'm just going to try and replicate the default one.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what your code is doing.  For a string such as "abcdefgh" (binary 0x6162636465666768), `binaryRepString` will contain the value `0110000101100010011000110110010001100101 0110011001100111`, which you then try to parse as a `long` in base 2.  This is 63 bits, which will fit into a `long`. However, if you add one more byte to the string, the intermediate value is now over 64 bits and no longer fits.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: Yeah I understood why I was getting the error. I first thought, well what can I use that holds larger numbers, and long story short I found a better way eventually (default hash algo) and all is well in the world now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to convert each character into a string (and that too in binary form) before converting it into a `long`? Why not just have a `long` value to which you add the `char`?

This is homework, so I'm not posting code. You can also see any good algorithm book or search the web) for more about hashing.

Edit:
I understand you don't want to just sum them up because anagrams will all have the same hash value. But I think you already know how to avoid that. Notice how by concatenating bits, you are basically adding bits to a value after having shifted them by some positions. i.e. "10101"+"10001" is the same as 1010100000+10001 - 21<<5+17.

By shifting each character by an amount proportional to its position in the string, the value added to the hash depends on both the value and position of the character. Also, observe the same effect can be had by simply multiplying rather than scaling.

Another thing to watch out for is the fact that a `long` has only 64 bits. you can only pack so many `char`s into it before it starts to overflow. So most practical hash functions take the value modulo some number. Of course that means there is only a limited number of possible hash values for an unlimited number of input strings. Collisions are inevitable, but well chosen values for your shift/multiplier and mod can minimize the number of collisions.

Comment: I don't want to sum the long values of the chars because then anagrams will have the same hashcode

Comment: Ahhhhhh, that makes sense. I think I'm going to try and do the default algo though.

Answer (score 0):

What is a good hash-function depends heavily on what you mean by good. I know this sounds cliché BUT it is just so true. To identify which hash-function is best for your specific problem-domain you have to specify:

- how long the input is
- which letters the input contains (letters in a certain alphabet, or just the 4 possible letters in genetic sequences, and if you want a really good hash function you even need to specify the expected probability of each letter)
- in which way you want to differentiate strings (your comment on MAK's answer shows that you want the hash to be different for permutations of the same string. So your `+=` is not a candidate, but see the link below for some functions that satisfy this requirement)

The combination of these 3 considerations allows you to select a good hash-function, but you first have to specify these 3 points.

As a side-note: obviously your `+=` into a Long only works for short strings. But even with a different hash-function you dont get unique hash values for every possible string that you can fit into the 64-bit Long (Java): You can distinguish only 2^64 strings even with a **perfect hash** function. In general if you have a hashtable that maps aKey->anObject you still store the original key (not just the hash-value that this bucket represents) so you can compare it with the requested key string.

Depending on your requirements you might want to take a look into the topic of **cryptographic hash-functions** to decide if *those* are what you want. However first take a look at the very good Wikipedia-entry which lists some **good hash-functions** and more importantly the situations for which they are good:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function